# Bevel modifier artifacts when designing house

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel, artifacts

I'm using the bevel modifier -- in conjunction with the subdivision surfaces modifier -- to make a house, but it's resulting in artifacts; namely, unsightly creases/dents at the edges of walls.

I tried removing the lines selected, but that didn't fix it and resulted in bad geometry.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Don't use the two modifiers together, instead increase the amount of segments in the Bevel modifier.

Comment: Yep, bevel over bevel will do somenasties. Also check for duplicate geometry, overlapping faces and incoherent normals